# Como listar una lista desplegable con Select2

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, select2

Un saludo,
estoy intentado listar un `select2` con `javascript`.

la respuesta de mi `controlador` con el `modelo` es efectiva.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no me esta mostrando el resultado en mi `select`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es la `function js`

```
 function listar_combo_cuna(){
        $.ajax({
            "url":"../controlador/invmaternidad/controlador_combo_cuna_listar.php",
            type:'POST'
        }).done(function(resp){
            var data = JSON.parse(resp);
            var cadena="";
            if(data.length>0){
                for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                    cadena+="<option value='"+data[i][0]+"'>"+data[i][1]+"</option>";
                }
                
                $("#cmb_cuna").html(cadena);
    
              
            }else{
                cadena+="<option value=''>NO SE ENCONTRARON REGISTROS</option>";
            }
            
        alert(resp);
        })
    
    }
```

este mi  `script` con el que llamo el `js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/invetario_maternidad.js?rev=<?php echo time();?>"></script>
```

este es mi `HTML`

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <label for="" class="fa fa-inbox"><b>&nbsp; Filtar por Cunas</b></label>
  <select class="js-example-basic-single form-control" name="state" id="cmb_cuna" style="width:100%;">
   </select>
</div>
```

y este `script` con el que llamo el `function`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    listar_combo_cuna();
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
} );
</script>
```

Muchas Gracias de antemano

Comment: La [documentación](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax) da un buen ejemplo para obtener los datos vía Ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te falta acceder a la propiedad `data`

ejemplo:

```
 var data = JSON.parse(resp);
 var cadena="";
 if(data.data.length>0){
   $.each( data.data, function( k, v ){
     cadena+="<option value='"+v.cuna_id+"'>"+v.cuna_nombre+"</option>";
   });      
 }else{
    cadena+="<option value=''>NO SE ENCONTRARON REGISTROS</option>";
 }
 $("#cmb_cuna").html(cadena);
```

Comment: me lista todos los elementos como "undefined"

Comment: @kevingarciamorales ya he realizado una modificacion vuelve a revisar

Comment: excelente, me funciona correctamente. muchas gracias por su apoyo. Bendiciones